# Json to pojo classes mapping with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

My json response is as follows

```
{"repositories": {

   "link":    [
            {
         "@rel": "self",
         "$": "http://localhost/content/repository"
      },
            {
         "@rel": "repositories",
         "$": "http://localhost/path/repository"
      }
   ]

}
}
```

I want the value of @rel in one of my variable in java.

I know how to create corresponding POJO classes for the JSON response and extract the values from it using Jackson library.I have created POJOs for quite a few json responses.But in this particular response i'm stuck because i have to create variable named "@rel" in my java class. but we can't create variable name starting with '@' in java(Or is der any way to do so which i don't know).

So how we can extract the value of @rel ?

the response can't change. I have to do some manipulation for extraction.

Please help.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn how to read JSON -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then you will see that "link" is an array, and hence should map to a Java List.  You must then iterate through the List to access "@rel".  "@rel" will not be a field in your main object, but in the List element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`@JsonProperty`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) annotation:

```
@JsonProperty("@rel")
private String rel;
```

You can also use a `Map<String, String>` as a *raw type*.